# Content in an embedded form textarea not being set to a process variable

Tags: camunda

Within a user task, the embedded form markup is

```
...
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control"
           cam-variable-name="jobDescription"
           cam-variable-type="String"
           name="jobDescription">
    </textarea>
  </div>
...
```

There is a process variable `jobDescription` that has been set - this has been verified via the Tomcat logs.

The problem is that content of the `textarea` is not being set to that of the process variable.

Camunda 7.10 is being used and I have checked the [Camunda manual 7.10](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.10/reference/embedded-forms/controls/textarea/)

If the `textarea` is changed to `input type="text"`, this shows the correct content.

Comment: seems you are using it exactly as documented: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/embedded-forms/controls/textarea/#binding-a-textarea-to-a-process-variable ... maybe worth filing a bug-issue?

Answer (score 0):

This works for Camunda 7.10.

To populate a `textarea`, the form needs to use the Camunda form events

```
<script cam-script type="text/form-script">   

  var variableManager = camForm.variableManager;

  var jobRequestInfo = $scope.jobRequestInfo = {};

  var jobDescription = $scope.jobDescription = {};


  camForm.on( 'form-loaded', function() {

    camForm.variableManager.fetchVariable( 'jobRequestInfo' );

    camForm.variableManager.fetchVariable( 'jobDescription' );

  });

  camForm.on( 'variables-fetched', function() {

    $scope.jobRequestInfo = camForm.variableManager.variable( 'jobRequestInfo' ).value;

    $scope.jobDescription = camForm.variableManager.variable( 'jobDescription' ).value;

  });

  camForm.on( 'variables-applied', function() {

    $( '[name="jobDescription"]' ).val( $scope.jobDescription );

  });

  camForm.on( 'submit', function( ev ) {

    ;

  });

</script>

...
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="jobDescription">Job Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control"
           ng-model="jobRequestInfo.description"
           name="jobDescription"
           rows="20">
    </textarea>
  </div>
...
```

There are two process-scoped variables:

- `jobDescription` a `String` that is populated with the initial value.
- `jobRequestInfo` a POJO with a field `description` that is populated with the final, edited value.

Note that Camunda does not fully support all HTML types such as radio buttons so beyond basic forms, using the Camunda form events is usually necessary.

Also, using Angular integration and POJO variables, as above, allows a significant reduction in process variables.